# Multiple Apple Facetime login userid

Tags: macos, facetime

Can I create multiple Facetime sessions in a single MAC OS using different Apple ID?

Comment: If you need to have a conference-call setup (multiple attendees simultaneously) then Skype or Google Hangouts will work just fine. If you need to have multiple FaceTime session windows running simultaneously, each with a one-to-one communication link, this will not work. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Trying to offer a Visual Communication service for Apple Facetime existing accounts. The mulatiple-session cap[ability was available until end of last year. Once YOSEMITE was officialy release, the OS-X does not support this functionality anymore. We have developed the code for accepting  Google hangouts clients.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you'll need to virtualize the OS and have multiple user accounts. It doesn't scale and doesn't work well since the software is designed to have one FaceTime active at any one time on the OS.

Comment: Virtualizatiion such as VMWARE does not recognize FACETIME services properly. Apple already knows about this situation. Similar results with Paralles

Comment: Alramir - Do you have a bug report radar to duplicate on FaceTime or submitted to http://www.openradar.me/?